# Arraylist not added to listview

Tags: android, arraylist

Hi in the below response is coming from server.Based on the response I am adding all the names to arraylist and them I am displaying in listview.

But My out was like this:

```
[{"ID":"148","Name":"fhh"},{"ID":"2","Name":"Building 1"},{"ID":"149","Name":"fgh"},{"ID":"3","Name":"Building 2"},{"ID":"150","Name":"rgg"},{"ID":"4","Name":"Building 3"},{"ID":"36","Name":"Building 4"},{"ID":"151","Name":"dfg"}]
I/System.out: true
I/chatty: uid=10434(com.deepshikha.lightingsystem) identical 1 line
I/System.out: true
I/System.out: [[fhh], [fhh], [fhh]]
    [fhh]
```

Excepted output:

fhh
fgh
rgg

```
if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ( );
                            Log.d ("Response body", new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( )));
                            //JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray ();
                            String Status = new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( ));


                                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                                 List <Collection> items = new ArrayList<>();
                                 JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                                try {
                                    jsonArray = new JSONArray (Status);
                                    jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject (0);
                                    arrayList = new ArrayList <> ( );
                                    for (int i=0;i<=jsonObject.length ();i++) {
                                        String id = jsonObject.getString ("ID");
                                        Collection name = Collections.singleton (jsonObject.getString ("Name"));
                                        //System.out.println (arrayList.add(i));
                                        System.out.println (arrayList.add (name));
                                        //Log.d ("name", String.valueOf (arrayList.addAll (name)));

                                    }
                                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getActivity ( ), R.layout.building_listview_item, arrayList);
                                        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter (arrayList, this);
                                        System.out.println (arrayList);
                                        arrayList.get (1);
                                    System.out.println (arrayList.get (1));
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();

                                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                     //   System.out.println (arrayList.add (name));




                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace ( );

                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you use `Collection name = Collections.singleton (jsonObject.getString ("Name"));`

directly use `arrayList.add (jsonObject.getString ("Name"))` to add name in list

and don't make a list of `Collection` make it of `String` like this

`List <String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: it is returning true

Comment: @jyothidadi that means item added to list

Comment: I am trying to display those response names into listview

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers how to print the names